# Dynamic Stylesheets with Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gulp, handlebars.js

I'm making a simple static website using `Express` and `express-handlebars` as my template engine. Currently, I have a `sass` folder which holds all my sass source files, which I compile with gulp into the `public` folder. I have a main layout file which contains the layout for the site, and then renders the content per page with `{{{body}}}`. Each page of content is a separate `.handlebars` file which renders into the layout's `{{{body}}}`. However, I need to inject stylesheets into each page depending on the page. For, example, right now I load the `main.css` file into every page, but for the home page I need to load `home.css` as well. I can easily build that file and put it in `/public`, but I'm not sure how to dynamically load the stylesheet with the same name as the page into each page as each page is just content, it doesn't have access to the layout which contains the `<head>` where I load stylesheets.

I could use a Handlebars helper to load the stylesheet with the same name as the page but that feels dirty, and then I cannot bundle the stylesheets together. What is the best approach to do this? I've never used Webpack but maybe I need to do that? Or is Gulp good enough? Thank you. My files are as follows:

TL;DR: For the following setup I need to render a stylesheet dynamically based on which page is being rendered into the handlebars layout.

`index.js`:

```
import express from 'express';
import exphbs from 'express-handlebars';

let app = express();

app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.engine('hbs', exphbs(
  { 
    defaultLayout: 'main', 
    extname: '.hbs'
  }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home',
    {
      title: 'Home'
    }
  );
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Started on port 3000...');
});
```

`views/layouts/main.hbs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- Need to render stylesheet for specific page here -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="layout">

        <div class="content">
          <div id="content-container">

            {{{body}}}

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

`views/home.hbs`:

```
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

`gulpfile.js`:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import sass from 'gulp-sass';
import stylish from 'jshint-stylish';

gulp.task('sass', () => {
  return gulp.src('./lib/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'expanded' }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'));
});
```

Comment: If you are able to write `{{title}}` in the layout, I don't see why you can't also output a path to a CSS file.

Comment: I am confused by this statement in your question: "...then I cannot bundle the stylesheets together". If you are bundling the stylesheets together then there would be no reason or way to load individual stylesheets based on the current page. I think you need to clarify what you are trying to do.